# How to flatten a dataframe in python pandas (perhaps similar to converting an identity matrix to a vector of ones)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data

```py
 df = pd.DataFrame(
 {
     'L': ['a',  'a',  'a',  'b',  'b',  'b',  'b'],
     'P': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p2', 'p1', 'p5'],
     'V': [8   , 12  , 13  ,  77 ,  22 ,  3  ,  11],
     }
     )
df = df.join( pd.get_dummies(df['P'] ).mul(df['V'], axis=0))
```

which prints out as :

```py
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
   L   P   V  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
0  a  p1   8   8   0   0   0   0
1  a  p2  12   0  12   0   0   0
2  a  p3  13   0   0  13   0   0
3  b  p4  77   0   0   0  77   0
4  b  p2  22   0  22   0   0   0
5  b  p1   3   3   0   0   0   0
6  b  p5  11   0   0   0   0  11
```

What I would like to do is, using pandas, convert this to the following :

```py
 L  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
 a   8  12  13   0   0
 b   3  22   0  77  11
```

I'm unsure whether 'flatten' is the correct word for this

## Edit

It would be appreciated if there was an explanation as to why this is too broad, as it seems to be quite a specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should changed with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and aggregate by column `df['L']` and `sum`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df['P']).mul(df['V'], axis=0).groupby(df['L']).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   L  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
0  a   8  12  13   0   0
1  b   3  22   0  77  11
```

Alternative is use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='L', columns='P', values='V', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
   L  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5
0  a   8  12  13   0   0
1  b   3  22   0  77  11
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's good or not, however it works:

```
In [3]: df.set_index(['L', 'P']).unstack().fillna(0)                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: 
     V                        
P   p1    p2    p3    p4    p5
L                             
a  8.0  12.0  13.0     0     0
b  3.0  22.0     0  77.0  11.0
```